# ssh via tmux send-keys and provide password

Tags: ssh, tmux

I want to automate stuff. I have bunch of servers that require login/pass auth upon sshing to them (this behavior I cannot change).

I want to write a bash script that have an array variable with N server urls, that prompts for login and password and then opens tmux, splits window onto N panes and ssh to particular server providing login and password when prompted.

```
for (( c=0 ; c<${#SERVERS[@]} ; c++ ))
do
    tmux select-pane -t $c
    tmux send-keys "ssh $USERNAME@${SERVERS[$c]}" Enter
done
```

How to provide password then automatically when prompted?

Answer (score 0):

First, for spawning multiple SSH sessions in parallel using `tmux`, see the [tmux-xpanes](https://github.com/greymd/tmux-xpanes) project which specializes in this.  You can then use the [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) tool to provide the password to SSH.

Comment: I am ok with spawning panes in a cycle, but can you give any example using `expect` for this problem?

Comment: Have you searched for how to use `expect` with SSH?

Comment: yes, but there's no any good example on how to use it when making a script that launches a lot of windows/panes, each autosshs to a server and provides password when prompted, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces. `xpanes` already handles the part of SSH'ing to many servers in many panes in parallel and has a README with lots of examples. It also turns on "pane synchronization". So if you enter a password once, it goes to all panes.  Is it OK if you have to enter the password just once instead of zero times? If so, then xpanes already has all the features you need.